# "2"-group cohomology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

In order to define the cohomology
of a topological group G, we first have to introduce the concept of a classifying space. A classifying space BG is the base space of a principal G bundle EG. The EG is the universal bundle: Any principal G bundle E over a manifold M allows a bundle map into the universal bundle, and any two such morphisms are smoothly homotopic. Given
$$
\gamma:  M \to BG 
$$ the induced map of the base manifolds, it is the so-called classifying map.

The topology of the bundle E is completely determined by the homotopy class of the classifying map $\gamma$. That is, the different components of the space Map(M,BG) correspond to the different bundles E over M. It can be shown that up to homotopy BG is uniquely determined by requiring EG to be contractible. That is, any contractible space with a free action of G is a realization of EG. In general, the classifying space BG of a compact group is an infinite-dimensional space.

**Attempt 1**:

Naively, we can have a generalized statement by modifying the map to a product of Eilenberg–MacLane space:
$$
\gamma:  M \to K(G_1,1) \times  K(G_2,2)
$$ 
where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two different groups. The $G_1$ can be non-abelian.

> - How can we be more precise to state the similar structure, defining a "2"-group cohomology, by generalizing the relation between the "group cohomology" and the "topological cohomology of classifying space"?
> - Is it necessary to have $G_2$ be abelian?

**Attempt 2**

- A more general classifying map may be:
  $$
  \gamma:  M \to BG'
  $$ 
  where $BG'$ is the possible fibration
  $$1 \to  K(G_2,2)\to  BG' \to  K(G_1,1) \to 1,$$
  where we may classify the fibration by Postinikov class $$[a] \in H^d(K(G_1,1), G_2).$$ Is this formulation precise?

> - How can we be sure that $d=3$ is the only solution and $[a] \in H^d(K(G_1,1), G_2)$ classifies all sensible "2" group cohomology?

Comment: What do you mean by "2-group cohomology"? Note that $K(G, n)$ only makes sense for $n > 1$ if $G$ is abelian, because higher homotopy groups are abelian.

Comment: I'm afraid its not at all clear what you are looking for. If you are looking for a cohomology theory of 2-groups, then these already exist. For example a google search for "crossed module cohomology" will give you results. Even searching for 2-group cohomology will give you a paper on Arxiv by Ginot.

Comment: As for your first comment note that $K(G_1,1)\times K(G_2,2)\simeq BG_1^\delta\times BK(G_2,1)\simeq B(G_2^\delta\times K(G_2,1))$, where $G_1^\delta$ is the (possibly non-abelian) group $G_1$ given the discrete topology, and $G_2$ is assumed abelian. Eilenberg-Mac lane spaces only give information on the underlying discrete group, and ignore any topological information it may hold.

Comment: Tyrone - thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following gives the answer you want, but there is a notion of **crossed module**  $\mathcal M =(\mu: M \to P)$ (due to JHC Whitehead)   where $M,P$ are groups and $P$ acts on $M$ satisfyng two rules, which I won't detail here. These crossed modules classify pointed homotopy $2$-types.  A crossed module $\mathcal M$ has a classifying space $B \mathcal M$. with first and second homotopy groups Coker $\mu$, Ker $\mu $ respectively. Full details are in the book [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html).

This book does not contain much on the topological or Lie case.

Comment: thanks for the comment +1